# iOS 6.1.2 receipt verification

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, verification, receipt

Some of my customers are complaining about getting errors when purchasing a product with iOS 6.1.2. The receipt verification (apple code) is failing the following test:

```
    NSString *localIdentifier                   = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    NSString *purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId        = [purchaseInfoFromTransaction objectForKey:@"unique-vendor-identifier"];
    NSString *verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier   = [verifiedReceiptReceiptDictionary objectForKey:@"unique_vendor_identifier"];


    if(verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier)
    {
        if (![purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId isEqualToString:verifiedReceiptVendorIdentifier]
            || ![purchaseInfoUniqueVendorId isEqualToString:localIdentifier])
        {
            // Comment this line out to test in the Simulator.
            [self error:@"verified/local problem"];

            failCount++;
        }
    }
```

Are other people also experiencing this issue?

Comment: YES! I added in-app purchase to an app and it fails for iOS 6.1. The "unique_vendor_identifier" fields does NOT match [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]  What to do?

Comment: ignore that verification...